# How to retain previous graphics in paint event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using

```
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, ph1.X,ph1.Y, 20, 20);
```

in the `panel1_Paint` event to draw an ellipse. The point `ph1` value comes from `textbox_KeyPress`.

I also added `panel1.Invalidate();` in the textbox_KeyPress event to force redraw on `panel1`.  What it is doing is clearing panel1 then add the new graphics.

**What I really want it to do is add the new graphics without clearing the previous graphics.**

Is there is a method for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is for you to create an ordered collection of objects (a List<> for example) which you would redraw each time that the OnPaint event is called.

Something like:

```
    // Your painting class. Only contains X and Y but could easily be expanded
    // to contain color and size info as well as drawing object type.
    class MyPaintingObject
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    // The class-level collection of painting objects to repaint with each invalidate call
    private List<MyPaintingObject> _paintingObjects = new List<MyPaintingObject>();

    // The UI which adds a new drawing object and calls invalidate
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hardcoded values 10 & 15 - replace with user-entered data
        _paintingObjects.Add(new MyPaintingObject{X=10, Y=15});
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // loop through List<> and paint each object
        foreach (var mpo in _paintingObjects)
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, mpo.X, mpo.Y, 20, 20);
    }
```

Comment: could u give an example ?!

Comment: @IbrahimHero: There you go. You will have to modify it for your own needs of course.