# can't draw new lines at PictureBox without old ones disappering

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

First I'm drawing one line

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{ 
   e.Graphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.Pens.White, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2);            
}
```

then I'm in other function changing variables `dx1`, `dy1`, `dx2`, `dy2` and calling `pictureBox1.Refresh();`

After that I have a new line painted, but old one disappeared.
How can I add a new one without disappearing of old one?

Comment: Don't forget about the "old" ones, use Graphics.DrawLines() instead.  Or draw into a bitmap.

Comment: The Paint event must draw all things you want to draw onto the control. Store all data in Lists ! For the difference between drawing __onto__ a control surface and __into__ a Bitmap the control displays, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797?s=2|0.0381#27341797)! For a longer discussion [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=9|0.1773#28716887)

Comment: For additional inspiration, see also [How to retain previous graphics in paint event?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27488584) and [Why does text drawn on a panel disappear?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/946150), among the many other questions related to trying to draw new things on a form without losing the old things.

Answer (score -2):

Try starting with an array of points, then handle the event by adding new points to the array, then draw the lines:

```
Point[] points = new Point[1];

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    int ptCount = points.Count();
    Array.Resize(ref points, ptCount + newPointAmt);


    // Add new points here.

    g.Clear(this.BackColor);
    g.DrawLines(new Pen(Color.White), points);
}
```